# show incomplete data in list missing bracket closing squre bracket

Tags: flutter

```
List<String> aList = [];
 List<int> imageBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Pdf = base64.encode(imageBytes);
    aList.add(base64Pdf);
output:
[ iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAeACAIAAACkA3BdAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4nOzde0ATV94
problem:after adding data in list [] closing is not done.
```

its show only opening [ bracket but not ] closing bracket.it show incomplete data in list
base64pdf show whole encoded file but in list it is shown incomplete and missing closing bracket

Comment: output of what? `print()` function? if so, most likely your list is to long and is cut off by a `print()` function

Comment: Yes if you are trying to print. print method is limited. You may try debugPrint() in such cases

Comment: I have also try debugPrint() but still it will not print all data which i have added on list.I want to pass List<String> alist=[]; to the api

Comment: `aList.forEach((s) => print(s.length))` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: try `developer.log(
      'responseBody',
      name: 'mystr',
      error: myBase64String,
    );` to print more chars in console

Comment: it print length :-2360824 .i print(s) then it show full data without square brackets like this:/4aVeRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAASACACBAABAAAAAAAAACECBAABAAAAAAAAACICB but i want this data in square bracket

Comment: String.length < 0 ??? and what you see if you `print(base64Pdf.length)`?

Comment: if i print(base64pdf.length) it show this length :2857664

Comment: i dont get it, what you see if you call `print('start of log'); aList.forEach((s) => print('item len is: ${s.length}')); print('end of log');`? just copy/paste the log output

Comment: I/flutter (29934): start of log
I/flutter (29934): item len is: 2857664
I/flutter (29934): end of log

Answer (score 0):

`print()` function did not print everything. 
you can see full result with debug mode and do copy paste if you need

[image]

Comment: Thank you ..I tried this now it will show whole content but how add this content into List<String> aList=[];

Comment: assume you want to manually add this string. you can use three single quote '''you string '''; to wrap your string. List<String> aList = [];
    String yourLongString = ''' yourlongstring ''';
    aList.add(yourLongString);